# Use Select box to group a grid Extjs

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

Is there any way to manipulate a grouping grid with an external control? For example, I want to use a select box and when I click on it, the grid become grouped.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manipulate the store of the grid:

use the `group` function to apply grouping.

use the `clearGrouping` function to remove all groups.